# Adding +2 to any number (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA code to add +2 to any string of numbers that are put in the function.

It works fine, until it reaches 6 and 7, then it breaks. I really have no clue why that is.

If you are wondering why I am doing this, this is part of an encryption algorithm and it is specifically looking to encrypt digits in a string.

My code is:

```
Sub AddNumbers()

Dim Nos As String
Dim AddNo As String
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim Split()

Nos = "0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U2").Value = Nos

Length = Len(Nos)
ReDim Split(Length)

For i = 1 To Length
    Found = False
    Split(i) = Mid(Nos, i, 1)
    For O = 48 To 55
        If Split(i) = Chr(O) Then
            Split(i) = Chr(O + 2)
            Found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next O
    If Split(i) = Chr(56) Then
        Split(i) = Chr(48)
    ElseIf Split(i) = Chr(57) Then
        Split(i) = Chr(49)
    End If
Next i

AddNo = Join(Split, "")

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U3").Value = AddNo

End Sub
```

I would really appreciate an insight to why it is breaking at 6 and 7.

Comment: Remember to tick `Require Variable Declaration` in the VBE Options.  You haven't declared `Length` so the code doesn't compile.  You should have an extra line:  `Dim Length As Long, i As Long, O As Long`.

Comment: so what should the ouput be?

Comment: @ScottCraner - should be "2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-1-32" - but when you run code, you will see that 8 and 9 do not come out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take me a moment, but you are double adding.

Look at your loop. When you encounter 6 (`Char(54)`) you add 2 and have 8 (`Char(56)`).

But then, after your loop you are testing again for same `Split(i)`. Char for 6 and 7 are now accordingly 56 and 57 - so you add another 2 to them.

```
If Split(i) = Chr(56) And Found = False Then
    Split(i) = Chr(48)
ElseIf Split(i) = Chr(57) And Found = False Then
    Split(i) = Chr(49)
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the actual function `Split`:

```
Sub AddNumbers()

Dim Nos As String
Dim AddNo As String
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim SplitStr() As String

Nos = "0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U2").Value = Nos

SplitStr = Split(Nos, "-")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(SplitStr) To UBound(SplitStr)
    Dim vlue As String
    vlue = StrConv(SplitStr(i), vbUnicode)
    Dim substr() As String
    substr = Split(Left(vlue, Len(vlue) - 1), vbNullChar)
    Dim j As Long
    For j = LBound(substr) To UBound(substr)
        Select Case substr(j)
            Case 8
                substr(j) = 0
            Case 9
                substr(j) = 1
            Case Else
                substr(j) = substr(j) + 2
        End Select
    Next j
    SplitStr(i) = Join(substr, "")
Next i


AddNo = Join(SplitStr, "-")

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U3").Value = AddNo


End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The overall problem is that you are using the Chr codes for numbers and not actual numbers.  This method only returns 1 digit because a Chr() refers to a list of single characters.

You are going to need to use Split (mySplit = Split(Nos,"-")) to return each number and work with those.

The lines

```
    If Split(i) = Chr(56) Then
        Split(i) = Chr(48)
    ElseIf Split(i) = Chr(57) Then
        Split(i) = Chr(49)
    End If
```

has me confused.  You are saying if the value is "8" change to "0" and if it is "9" change to "1"

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it:

```
Sub AddNumbers()

    Dim Nos As String, Nos2 As String
    Dim NumSplit As Variant
    Dim Num As Variant
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim i As Long


    Nos = "0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U2").Value = Nos

    NumSplit = Split(Nos, "-")

    For Each Num In NumSplit
        For i = 1 To Len(Num)
            tmp = tmp & Mid(Num, i, 1) + 2
        Next i
        Nos2 = Nos2 & tmp & "-"
        tmp = ""
    Next Num
    Nos2 = Left(Nos2, Len(Nos2) - 1)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U3").Value = Nos2

End Sub
```

It's a bit messy, but shows the basic idea of splitting the original array into the separate numbers.
The `For....Next` loop inside the `For...Each` loop takes care of any numbers with more than one digit (giving the 32).